# Inserting a task from a Force.com Site

Tags: soql, force.com-sites, tasks

I have a Force.com Site with a controller inserting a new Task. I noticed that I receive no error on the page, but the Task is not created. When I access to the same page internally (from `https://.../apex/myPage`), the Task is created.

I noticed that there're no check boxes to allow Activity/Task/Event creation. So my question: is it possible?

Thanks.

**UPDATE 2013-03-05**

Here's my controller. The method `handler` is called using the `action="handler"` from `<apex:page>`

```
public with sharing class Testing {

    public PageReference handler() {
        Task act = new Task(
            RecordTypeId    = '012c00000000fCS',
            Subject         = 'Testing'
        );

        try {
            insert act;
        } catch (DmlException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Error:' + e));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible because the "Edit Task" permission is required in order to create tasks. Site public access settings doesn't expose this permission. You would have to write an Apex Web Service to accomplish this.

Check out this article from Salesforce to help get you started on a Web Service.
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts

Comment: But why can I create any other record from any object, but not the `Task` or `Event` one?

Comment: Because the "Edit Task" permission is required in order to create tasks. Site public access settings doesn't expose this permission.